# Sending image and additional info via HTTP

Tags: javascript, html, express

I want to send and image AND other text information,
I saw that for the image I need to use `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in the form. But doing this make me unable to see the other information needed.

```html
 <form action="/new" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
      <input type="text" id="name" value=""/>
      <input type="file" name="image" accept="image/*"  value="Compagny Logo"/>
      <input type="submit" value="Load compagny"/>
</form>
```

```js
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, callBack) => {
        callBack(null, './public/images/')
    },
    filename: (req, file, callBack) => {
        callBack(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname))
    }
})
 
var upload = multer({
    storage: storage
});

router.post("/new", upload.single('image'), (req, res) => {
        console.log(req.file.filename) // work
        console.log(req.name) // does'nt work
    }
});
```

Is there and other `enctype` I need to use ?

Comment: did you tried `req.body.name`

Comment: You can remove enctype, use this SO page to help you convert your image into a base64 string (https://stackoverflow.com/a/6150397/3155240), send both strings to your express server, and in your express / node code convert the base64 string to an image and write it to a file, which is how most people do it, I believe.

Comment: nope  Ifaruki it's 'undefined'
and thank us @Shmack i'll do that